# How to use GWTBootstrap with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, twitter-bootstrap, gwt-bootstrap

I downloaded the Twitter Bootstrap for GWT zip from https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap. I am new to GWT and I haven't yet found proper documentation or a tutorial on how to use the libraries with Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

As it's created as a `maven` project, you need to use `m2eclipse` plugin. You can start with cloning that outside eclipse and then you can import it into eclipse as an existing maven project. `m2eclipse` plugin will help you in doing that. For exact steps or tutorial, you can just google.

Comment: thanks but i hear 'maven' and 'creating a jar out of it' everywhere, wish i could find a simpler method or a step by step somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) build, configure [m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse) in eclipse and go through [Getting Started With GWT Bootstrap](http://prayag-waves.blogspot.com/2012/09/getting-started-with-gwt-bootstrap.html)

### The steps include :

**STEP 1-A :** add `gwt-bootstrap` maven dependency in `pom.xml`

```
 <!-- gwt-bootstrap dependencies start -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.gwtbootstrap</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-bootstrap</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<!-- gwt-bootstrap dependencies end -->
```

**STEP 1-B :** add `gwt-bootstrap` maven repository in `pom.xml`

```
 <repository>
 <id>sonatype</id>
 <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
 <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
 <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
 </repository>
```

**STEP 2 : Configuring module** - inherit the GWT-Bootstrap widget library

```
<!--  inherit the GWT-Bootstrap widget library -->
<inherits name="com.github.gwtbootstrap.Bootstrap"/>
<!--  end of inherit the GWT-Bootstrap widget library -->
```

**STEP 3 : using in UiBinder**

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
xmlns:w="urn:import:com.zcode.t.client.ui.widget" 
xmlns:c="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client"
xmlns:gwt="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client"
xmlns:b="urn:import:com.github.gwtbootstrap.client.ui"
>
<g:HTMLPanel>
<b:Button ui:field="saveBtn"/>
 </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use maven, you can follow these steps:

1. Download a version of library from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap).
2. Add the .jar file to your build path of Eclipse project
3. Add to your `Module.gwt.xml` file:

`<inherits name ="com.github.gwtbootstrap.Bootstrap"/>`

Now you can use `gwtbootstrap` with only-Java code or UIBinder